# Recreating QGIS "Save Raster as Rendered Image" using GDAL in Python API

Tags: image, gdal, qgis

I have a set of Geotiff that will be inputted in a machine learning model. The problem is that Geotiff file is not considered as an image for some reason and the model only takes in image files.

I found that using QGIS "save Raster as Rendered Image" solves this problem. I am now trying to recreate that feature in gdal so that it can be incorporated in the machine learning model.

Does someone know how to recreate this? Thank you!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255336/convert-tif-to-png-without-normalizing-alpha

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. A Geotiff file already is "an image". But you probably mean that you have some issues with the datatype or scaling of the data? It would be best to address that directly.